# New windows open outside of display area - What can I do?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

There is a bug within Windows that has annoyed me for years.  Well, I assume it's a bug.  Rarely (within the frequency of once a year or so) I'll open an application (doesn't matter) that implements dialogs.  When I open a dialog, it opens off the edge of the screen.  In other words, you see the dialog window on your task bar but you can't see the window.

I right-click on the task bar item and I select "move". I get the "move" cursor but, since the window is open outside the screen's viewing area, I can't move it. The only way to view the dialog is to select the "Maximize" option.  This is an okay solution, however, if the dialog is one that does not allow for maximization you're screwed.

Maybe this is a bug with the particular application that executes the dialog.  (The one annoying me today is SQL Server Management Studio.)

My question is, has anyone else seen this bug and **is there a way to "move" these hidden windows** so that I can use them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you click move (as you already described doing), use your arrow keys until you can see it. Then hit enter once it is where you want it. When you close the window, hold the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key down as that is often (not always) a way that forces the location to save.

Comment: I have modal dialogs where there is no Move entry in the task bar item's menu. In that case hitting Alt-hyphen works for me.

Comment: Ah, always so simple.  Thank you.  Just out of curiosity, are you familiar with this annoyance?  I forgot to mention that I've typically seen this on my dev PC, which has two monitors.  I would assume that there is a bug caching the dialog location, when associated with dual-screens.

Comment: @Ulrich Gerhardt That is good to know.

Comment: @RLH: I suppose that's a problem with the respective applications, **not** with Windows, as Windows doesn't store windows positions.

Comment: Aaargh: It's Alt- **Space**, not hyphen.

Comment: I don't know if I would call it a bug, but they clearly do not have any limitation on where the window can be saved to. I have encountered this before, as you have, and this has always worked for me.

Comment: It's actually sufficient to press one arrow key once and then just move the mouse without clicking, then click once to set the new window position. It'll save you a handful of keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

This way worked for me : (had the windows totally off the screen)

- Click Alt+Tab, in order to choose the off screen application
- Click Alt-Space, it will open the windows menu (even if we can't see it)
- Click M, it select the "move" option
- Move the windows with the arrows on keyboard

Comment: It's actually sufficient to press one arrow key once and then just move the mouse without clicking, then click once to set the new window position. It'll save you a handful of keystrokes.